# Big Sur - Mouse bug - cursor and pointer mismatch

Tags: macos, accessibility, macos-big-sur, external-display, magic-mouse

I updated my Mid 2015 15" MacBook Pro to Big Sur (11.1) a few days ago, and after I connected my external display (Dell U2718Q scaled to 2560x1440)(running in extended destop mode, using that display and the internal laptop display) and my Magic Mouse, I had issues that the mouse cursor sometimes itself does not represent the pointer.

When I press the mouse button, the click itself happens somewhere else on the screen. The cursor/pointer mismatch is consistent as long as I move around on the screen. So if it's 100px to the left and 200px to the top, it will always be like that, until I move the mouse once to the top of the display, then it's back in sync.

In the most extreme case my mouse cursor was on the right (internal) display and the pointer itself was on the left (external) display.

I have already restarted the Mac and tried the NVRAM reset. and already deleted and reconnected the Magic Mouse. (Both just via Bluetooth and by deleting the .plist files in ~/Library/preferences/

I can not fully confirm yet, but pretty sure the same issue happens if i just use the integrated trackpad.

When I used the Mac over the holidays before I connected display and Magic Mouse, there was no problem, neither was there a problem before I upgraded with the same setup to Big Sur.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/i4vmpf/mouse_pointer_clicks_in_the_wrong_location_when/gifnxjn/

I found this reddit post, so I'm not alone with this bug, but that one answer actually pointed me to the reason and a temporary solution.

This behavior seems to be caused by the accessibility zoom feature (which i had enabled as picture in picture, temporary zoom by hitting alt+command). 
Since I disabled that, the mouse seems to work just fine again.

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a *programming* question. Might be better on Super User.